# Defining a ResourceDictionary only once

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, resourcedictionary

i have the following ResourceDictonary

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                    xmlns:SharedHelpers="clr-namespace:Shared.Helpers;assembly=Shared"
                    xmlns:SharedViewModels ="clr-namespace:Shared.ViewModels;assembly=Shared"
                    xmlns:SharedViews="clr-namespace:Shared.Views;assembly=Shared"
                    >

<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type SharedViewModels:DatabaseViewModel}">
   <SharedViews:DatabaseView/>
</DataTemplate>

<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type SharedViewModels:ProxyViewModel}">
  <SharedViews:ProxiesView/>
</DataTemplate>

<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type SharedViewModels:AppUserViewModel}">
   <SharedViews:AppUserView/>
</DataTemplate>
<!--ViewModels-->
<SharedViewModels:DatabaseViewModel x:Key="DatabaseViewModel"/>
<SharedViewModels:AppUserViewModel x:Key="AppUserViewModel"/>
<SharedViewModels:ProxyViewModel x:Key="ProxyViewModel"/>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

as you can see those resource are static and i want to access them from my other libraries and classes
so what i did is in my App.xaml i did define the dictionary as the following

```
 <Application.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary x:Name="dict"  Source="ResourceDict.xaml"/>
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Application.Resources>
```

from my code behind i need to access the instances in this dictionary without having to redefine it, so i found

`var databaseViewModelInstance = Application.Current.Resources.MergedDictionaries["dict"]["DatabaseViewModel"] as Shared.ViewModels.DatabaseViewModel;`

but the problem is it allows me to access the dictionary only by index and not by its name, how can i access the dictionary by its name without having to define a new resource dictionary instance in every class that i want to access it from?

the following works just fine

```
var databaseViewModelInstance = Application.Current.Resources.MergedDictionaries[0]["DatabaseViewModel"] as Shared.ViewModels.DatabaseViewModel;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Accessing a resource dictionary by name is a bit problematic since it doesn't derive from `FrameworkElement` and thus doesn't have a `Name` property. If it had, you could do the following:

```
Application.Current.Resources.MergedDictionaries
                             .First(x => x.Name == "dict")["DatabaseViewModel"] as Shared.ViewModels.DatabaseViewModel;
```

However, instead of filtering by name, you can filter by source:

```
Application.Current.Resources.MergedDictionaries
                             .First(x => x.Source.OriginalString == "ResourceDict.xaml")["DatabaseViewModel"] as Shared.ViewModels.DatabaseViewModel;
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if you can get a ResourceDictionary from a MergedDictionaries collection by name. However, it looks as though you only want to access it to get a particular resource within it (makes sense).

In this case, you may want to think about using [FrameworkElement.TryFindResource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.tryfindresource%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

This should search up the logical tree and arrive at your App.xaml level eventually. For clarity, you should be able to get your **DatabaseViewModel** by

```
FrameworkElement fe = new FrameworkElement();
var myResource = fe.TryFindResource("DatabaseViewModel");
```